# How can I relate product to itself in OpenERP 8 (Odoo) both ways?

Tags: odoo, openerp-8

On OpenERP 8 (Odoo), I'm developing a module that should add a field **Related Products**, it should relate products both ways. I added a many2many field

```
class product_template(osv.Model):
    _name = 'product.template'
    _inherit = 'product.template'
    _columns = {
        'related_products': fields.many2many('product.template', 'rel_related_product', 'product_id', string="Related Products"),
    }
```

The problem is that I can relate the product only one way. I.e. if I relate ProductB to ProductA, I can only see the relationship inside ProductA and not the otherway around

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 1):

Why cant you use one2many relation. Like parent child relation in categories.
Or
you may be trying to get something similar to the bom structure. Please install the MRP module and check how bom structure is defined

Comment: I think that this will create a hierarchal structure, which is not always the case. I'm looking for a flat structure, where any sort of items may be related to each other. Am I correct?

Comment: any sort of items??i didnt get you.

Comment: Let me explain. An item (Device) and an item (screwdriver) make sense to be related as a parent-child. But an item (Cellphone) and an item (Laptop) are not.

Does what I say make sense?

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
class product_template(osv.Model):
    _name = 'product.template'
    _inherit = 'product.template'

    _columns = {
            'related_products': fields.many2many('product.template', 'rel_related_product', 'product_id', 'product_template_id', string="Related Products"),
        }
```

Comment: I noticed that you just added `'product_template_id'` parameter. I tried this but still it doesn't display the product on the other end

I.e. When I add a ProductB in the Related Products in ProductA, I can't see ProductA when I open ProductB